# Numeric value is not recognized SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

I have below table called "inspection" and schema called "raw" . Both column Boro, Inspection_date are varchar

[image]

I am trying to do transformation and save in new schema called "curated" and table name called "insp"

Below is the code I've written

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA Curated;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE CURATED.Insp (
  "Total Inspections" INTEGER,
  Boro VARCHAR(50),
  Year INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO curated.Insp ("Total Inspections", Boro, Year)
SELECT Boro, COUNT(*) AS "Total Inspections", YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) AS "Year"
FROM raw.inspection
WHERE YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) >= 2000 AND Boro NOT LIKE 0
GROUP BY YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)),BORO
ORDER BY YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) DESC;
```

I am getting below error

```
Numeric value 'Bronx' is not recognized
```

Not sure what is the issue here? Boro column has 0, but I have created the column as a varchar. Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Check column order in source and destination:INSERT INTO curated.Insp (``"Total Inspections"``, Boro, Year)
SELECT ``Boro``, COUNT(*) AS "Total Inspections", YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) AS "Year"

Comment: I have removed the <ansi-sql> tag since several non-ANSI functions are used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the order of the columns in the `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO curated.Insp ("Total Inspections", Boro, Year)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total Inspections", Boro,  YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) AS "Year"
FROM raw.inspection
WHERE YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) >= 2000 AND Boro NOT LIKE 0
GROUP BY YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)),BORO
ORDER BY YEAR(CAST(Inspection_date AS DATE)) DESC;
```